# Page doesn't exist in lightning

Tags: error, sandbox

I have moved my code from Dev to Sit using changesets.

My Code:

```
window.open('/one/one.app#/n/Product_Generation_Grid?grid='+grid+'&rec='+marketSegment, '_parent');
```

But when I try to access this url in SIT I'm getting this error 
"Page doesn't exist".

I just copy paste the url in both dev & sit as

Dev -- https://testtrial--dev.lightning.force.com/one/one.app#/n/Product_Generation_Grid -- Working Fine

Sit -- https://testtrial--sit.lightning.force.com/one/one.app#/n/Product_Generation_Grid -- Page doesn't Exist Error

What I have missed here

I have checked everything in both orgs and looks identical. Am I missing anything?

Comment: `window.open` is not the correct way to perform the navigation in lightning. Refer this [trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_dev_visualforce/units/lex_dev_visualforce_navigation).

Comment: Modified the Question just please check. I have tried using pagereference as well but doesn't work

Comment: Are you working with namespaces? If so, you might need to add it. not sure if it goes where the `/n/` is but in my org I can replace the `/c/` in app urls with my Namespace `.lightning.force.com/c/my.app`

Comment: Thanks all for your assistance. I have changed the url to https://testtrial--dev.lightning.force.com/one/one.app#/n/Product_Generation_Grid__c/new and its working fine.